# Unable to get_text from select_one using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the time from the below HTML but am unable to use `get_text` with `select_one` to extract the `data-published-date` or `datetime` within `<time class = "published-date relative-date" ... /time>`.

```
<div class="content">
       <header>
        <h3 class="article-name">
         Curious Kids: Why is the Moon Called the Moon?
        </h3>
        <p class="byline">
         <span class="by-author">
          By
          <span style="white-space:nowrap">
           Toby Brown
          </span>
         </span>
         <time class="published-date relative-date" data-published-date="2019-12-13T12:00:28Z" datetime="2019-12-13T12:00:28Z">
         </time>
        </p>
       </header>
```

Using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.space.com/news'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

contents = soup.select('.content')
headlines = []
for item in contents:
  h_line = item.select_one('.article-name').get_text()
  author = item.select_one('.byline > span:nth-of-type(1) > span:nth-of-type(1)').get_text().strip()
  synopsis = item.select_one('.synopsis').get_text().strip() 
  date = item.select_one('.byline > time').get_text() 
  newsline = {'Headline': h_line, 'Author': author, 'Synopsis': synopsis, 'Date': dates}
  headlines.append(newsline) 

for line in headlines:   
  print(line)
```

Yields a traceback error, claiming it is 'NoneType'. Also, answers can only use BeautifulSoup parsing, no RegEx.

***UPDATE:
I modified the answer to be able to be used in my for loop (so that I can iterate through the source code for all headlines)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.space.com/news'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

contents = soup.select('.content')
headlines = []
for item in contents:
  h_line = item.select_one('.article-name').get_text()
  author = item.select_one('.byline > span:nth-of-type(1) > span:nth-of-type(1)').get_text().strip()
  synopsis = item.select_one('.synopsis').get_text().strip() 
  dates = item.select_one('time').get('data-published-date')
  newsline = {'Headline': h_line, 'Author': author, 'Synopsis': synopsis, 'Date & Time Published': dates}
  headlines.append(newsline) 

for line in headlines:   
  print(line)
```

Comment: check my answer below. http://www.sharecsv.com/s/001acc19d90bc2656b2fbcb421ad34c9/output.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """
<div class="content">
       <header>
        <h3 class="article-name">
         Curious Kids: Why is the Moon Called the Moon?
        </h3>
        <p class="byline">
         <span class="by-author">
          By
          <span style="white-space:nowrap">
           Toby Brown
          </span>
         </span>
         <time class="published-date relative-date" data-published-date="2019-12-13T12:00:28Z" datetime="2019-12-13T12:00:28Z">
         </time>
        </p>
       </header>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('time', {'class': 'published-date relative-date'}):
    print(item.get('data-published-date'))
```

Output:

```
2019-12-13T12:00:28Z
```

Deep Version:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.space.com/news')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

headline = []
author = []
syn = []
time = []
for item in soup.findAll('h3', {'class': 'article-name'}):
    headline.append(item.text)
for item in soup.findAll('span', {'style': 'white-space:nowrap'}):
    author.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
for item in soup.findAll('p', {'class': 'synopsis'}):
    syn.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
for item in soup.findAll('time', {'class': 'published-date relative-date'}):
    time.append(item.get('data-published-date'))

for item in zip(headline, author, syn, time):
    print(item)
```

Comment: this is highly inefficient as you are running four seperate for-loops here to get results

Comment: @aws_apprentice i would be interested to see your `one` `loop` which will lead to big line.

Comment: sure, I just posted my answer which uses only one loop and is still readable, showing OP how to do this the wrong way is not a correct answer in my opinion

Comment: @aws_apprentice if it's only `one` `loop` in your opinion so let me inform you that you are looping over `contents` which include `for loop` of `find_all`

Comment: however `bs4` works under the hood is not my concern, tacking on extra loops on top of what is happening is not recommended, your answer is inefficient and in my opinion not the right way to go about the problem. teaching a beginner to add more loops is not a good thing

Comment: @aws_apprentice I'm looping 4 times. but you looping over a loop which is called each time to find the item. so it's means `hey loop find item# 1` then `hey loop find item#2`. which means the same.

Comment: if you are talking about the ‘find’ operation that I call in every loop, sure maybe bs4 is running something like that under the hood, however the document I am scanning is small, it’s one tiny div, as opposed to you who scans the whole document every single time. i’m done arguing with you, I suggest going back to review big O notation to understand why your answer is highly inefficient

Comment: @aws_apprentice I'm not talking about `find` at all. Here is content which hold for loop of `find_all` `contents = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'content'})`. which is called each time for each operation under `for content in contents:`. that's can be verified, if you count how many loops your program running. if you are talking about one `loop` so it's should be like this https://bpaste.net/show/XPIAK

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be more efficient since it only loops once.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.space.com/news')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
contents = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'content'})

headlines = []
for content in contents:
    h_line = content.h3.text
    author = content.span.text.strip('\n').split('\n\n')[-1]
    synopsis = content.find('p', {'class': 'synopsis'}).text.strip('\n')
    dates = content.time['data-published-date']
    newsline = {'Headline': h_line, 'Author': author, 'Synopsis': synopsis, 'Date & Time Published': dates}
    headlines.append(newsline)

print(headlines[0])

{'Author': 'Doris Elin Urrutia ',
 'Date & Time Published': '2019-12-13T21:55:10Z',
 'Headline': 'Space Photos: The Most Amazing Images This Week!',
 'Synopsis': 'Here are our picks for the most amazing space photos of the week.'}
```